# using spring security, two formLogin's not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Here's my code:

```
    @Bean
@Order(1)
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
            authorize.requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/venues").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/order").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/graphiql").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            authorize.requestMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
        }
        //.addFilterBefore(JsonAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .formLogin { form ->
            form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                .permitAll()
        }
        //.addFilterAt(jsonAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .logout { logout ->
            logout
                .logoutRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .permitAll()
        }
    return http.build()
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun filterChainApp(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin { form ->
            form
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login_m")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .successHandler(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
                    objectMapper,
                    userDetailsService!!,
                    queryService,
                    userRepository
                ))
                .failureHandler(CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        }
    return http.build()
}
```

I want to have a normal login page, and I want to just post login creds to login_m, and handle success differently. But, when I post to login_m, it's handled by the /login formLogin instance. How can I have 2 login endpoints, with different success behavior?